# How to make RadioGroup not overlap with Button?

Tags: android, xml

I was making an application layout at android studio, there I looked at the right design, but when I tried it on my device, I experienced RadioGroup overlapping with Button. 
I am new to making an android application, so I have been trying and searching for information for days but haven't received the answer. can anyone help me?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLatas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_rounded"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderWaktuMati"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#008577"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="DATA MENINGGAL"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextNama"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Hari (Jawa)"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/judulTglMasehi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Tanggal (Masehi)"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/judulTglJawa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/judulTglMasehi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Tanggal (Jawa)"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitikDua1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titikDua2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titikDua"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextHariJawa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextNama"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/titikDua"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTglMasehi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/titikDua"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTglJawa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/JudulHari"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/titikDua"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgProfil"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rounded_biru"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nama orang yang meninggal"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#B3B2B2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/HeaderWaktuMati"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/CheckSblm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
            android:text="Sebelum Magrib"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/CheckSsdh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
            android:text="Sesudah Magrib"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/GantiTanggal"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tanggalan"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/GantiTanggal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GantiTanggal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GantiTanggal"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rounded_biru"
        android:src="@drawable/layout_rounded_biru"
        android:text="HITUNG"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imgProfil"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-103dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-103dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:onClick="onUploadImageClick"
        android:src="@drawable/iconrounded"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try padding for text.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from your circle image view and changing your `android:layout_marginTop`value to a larger value.

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imgProfil"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/HeaderWaktuMati" 
                                                    <- remove centerVertical 
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" <- change this value, 65dp may be too much, adjust accordingly
        android:layout_marginEnd="-105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
        android:onClick="onUploadImageClick"
        android:src="@drawable/iconrounded"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```